# Assigning new value to the highest occurrence value in R

Tags: r

I have data set similar to this:

```
df_out <- data.frame(
  "name" = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"),
  "Factor1"=rep(c("A","B","C"),times= c(2,1,5)),
  "col3"=rep(c("T","S"),times= c(2,6)),
  "col4"=rep(c("E","D"),times= c(6,2)))
df_out
```

I want to mutate all the columns and assign new value to them based on their counts so for all the columns I want the value with the highest occurrence to be the consensus and all of the rest values to be the non consensus and NA stay as it.
So the output similar to this:

```
df_out2 <- data.frame(
  "name" = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"),
  "Factor1"=rep(c("non-consensus","consensus"),times= c(3,5)),
  "col3"=rep(c("non-consensus","consensus"),times= c(2,6)),
  "col4"=rep(c("consensus","non-consensus"),times= c(6,2)))
df_out2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI you don’t need to (and it makes no sense to) quote argument names, any more than you’d quote other variable names. The fact that R even allows this is due to weird a flaw of the language.

Comment: @– 
Konrad Rudolph  Sorry if i did not understand you but i want to group every column  into 2 groups, the letters with the highest value will be 1 category and all the rest letters in the column will be under another group.

Comment: I’m just saying that instead of writing `data.frame("name" = …)` you can/should write `data.frame(name = …)`. String-quoting argument names makes no sense and is misleading, since these are *not* strings. R allows using string quotes here for historical reasons.

Comment: @– 
Konrad Rudolph
Thanks for your clarification, its appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a base R approach:

```
df_out2 <- 
cbind(df_out$name,
      df_out[-1] |> ## don't manipulate name column
      lapply(function(column){ ## apply this function to each column
        level_counts = table(column) ## count observations per factor level        
        ifelse(level_counts[column] == max(level_counts),
               'consensus', 'non consensus'
               )
      }
      ) |> as.data.frame() ## convert list of columns to data frame
      )
```

```
  df_out$name       Factor1          col3          col4
1           1 non consensus non consensus     consensus
2           2 non consensus non consensus     consensus
3           3 non consensus     consensus     consensus
4           4     consensus     consensus     consensus
5           5     consensus     consensus     consensus
6           6     consensus     consensus     consensus
7           7     consensus     consensus non consensus
8           8     consensus     consensus non consensus
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_out %>%
  mutate(across(Factor1:col4, 
    ~ ifelse(.x == names(rev(sort(table(.x))))[1], "consensus", "non-consensus")))
#>   name       Factor1          col3          col4
#> 1    1 non-consensus non-consensus     consensus
#> 2    2 non-consensus non-consensus     consensus
#> 3    3 non-consensus     consensus     consensus
#> 4    4     consensus     consensus     consensus
#> 5    5     consensus     consensus     consensus
#> 6    6     consensus     consensus     consensus
#> 7    7     consensus     consensus non-consensus
#> 8    8     consensus     consensus non-consensus
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with pivoting: The key points are setting the grouping variable at the right position and remove the `n` to get the desired solution:

`add_count` is same as `group_by(...) and mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_out %>%
  pivot_longer(-name, 
               names_to = "Factors",
               values_to= "Values") %>% 
  add_count(Factors, Values) %>% 
  group_by(Factors) %>% 
  mutate(Values = ifelse(n==max(n), "consensus", "non-consensus")) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Factors,
              values_from = Values)
```

Comment: @ Hi TarJae , Thank you very much for your code. What if i have NA in my data? how can I add this code in mutate please?

Comment: In which part you suppose to have NA in Factor or col3 etc.. ?

Comment: Adding this two lines `mutate(col3 = ifelse(row_number()==4, NA_character_, col3),
         col4 = ifelse(col4=="E", NA_character_, col4)) %>%` which add NA's to your data frame will result in the same output with my above added code!